# Bootstrap 4 throwing errors, Uncaught TypeError?

Tags: javascript, html

Just looking at the syntax I believe it has something to do with bootstraps JS

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined util.js:56
    at util.js:56
    at util.js:10
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
    at bootstrap.min.js:6
```

Basically the issue on my website is the fact that I'm using a basic login page, when I enter the login page, I cannot return to the homepage without editing the URL to go to Default.aspx, the ReturnURL doesnt actually work and just displays the ReturnUrl in the URL bar.

```
/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fAccount%2fChangePassword.aspx
```

Comment: what is the order of your file imports ?

Comment: <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Styles/Site.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
It was the order that was the issue

Comment: well, you should reverse the order of your javascript files, jquery should be first then bootstrap second.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think its coming from Js order you called.
Jquery must be called first and after that called bootstrap script files.

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```